# How can I set up a Gatsby project with typescript and linting

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, babeljs, static-analysis, gatsby

I want to set up a Gatsby project with Typescript and linting that allows me to detect any type or other errors both on my text editor (project wide error detection) and also have warnings and errors logged on my terminal when I am running yarn develop.

At my company we have this setup with tslint and no babel so typescript does both the transpiling and the type checking. However, Gatsby uses babel internally and I believe that is causing problems because babel does not execute type checking when the code is running.

I have tried different approaches to accomplish this task based on these 3 articles.

https://www.arden.nl/setting-up-a-gatsby-js-starter-with-type-script-es-lint-prettier-and-pre-commit-hooks

https://medium.com/@thetrevorharmon/how-to-make-a-super-fast-static-site-with-gatsby-typescript-and-sass-3742c00d4524

https://medium.com/maxime-heckel/getting-started-with-typescript-on-gatsby-8544b47c1d27

But none of these solutions left me completely satisfied because linting is not handled the way I want it. ( I dont want to run scripts for type cheking, I want to see it instantly on the terminal)

My requirements are these:

- Use Gatsby
- Use Typescript
- When I run yarn develop I want all syntax errors and type checking errors display on the terminal.
- Have all syntactical and type-checking errors display in VScode (project wide even closed files, so es-lint might be a no go)
- Bonus: have prettier run on top of this

Have I missed something or is this too much to ask? :-)

Comment: Are you able to show what you have tried already?